# SMS Relay to macOS without iMessage?

Tags: macos, messages, sms, ios, facetime

Is it possible to relay SMS to macOS without using iMessage? I want to only use a phone carrier's SMS service, without iMessage, but would like to leverage the Mac Messages app.

If I can relay standard audio phone calls to a Mac, answering them through FaceTime, why is relaying SMS to Messages dependent on iMessage? Seems like a workaround should exist.

Comment: Do you have to use the default macOS Messages app? Or would you be happy with any solution?

Comment: @Monomeeth Any solution I suppose

Comment: While I cannot provide a detailed solution at the moment, I know that I am able to send and receive standard SMS on macOS via the messages application.

Comment: @MichaelVoccola Yes you can send standard SMS through the Messages app, but it requires you be signed into iMessage. Check the app Preferences.